# Question about "M" in a short exact sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, exact-sequence

> If we have a splitting short exact sequence $0\to L\stackrel {\alpha}\to M\stackrel{\beta}\to N\to 0$ with $r$ as a retraction of $\alpha$. Is it true then that $\alpha(L)\cup \ker(r)=M$?

Comment: If you consider pretty much **any** example, you'll answer the question yourself.

Comment: Then don't. But please do not delete perfectly good answers you have *already* spent your energy on, independently of the thankfulness or otherwise of the OP. There are *many* people coming to the site to learn math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $0\to\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z\to 0$. Is ($\mathbb Z\times \{0\})\cup(\{0\}\times\mathbb Z)=\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$?